# Section/subsection enumeration in tufte-handout

Tags: tufte

Any thoughts how I can numbers to section titles in `tufte-handouts`? 
I have tried the solutions suggested here, but they don't seem to work for this template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the `secnumdepth` counter to your desired level should do the trick:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

% Turn on numbering for section and subsection headings
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

% Provide dummy text
\usepackage{blindtext}

% Temporarily work around Tufte-LaTeX's lack of \subsubsection
\let\subsubsection\subsection

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```